# Redistribution Vs Static linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

We are building our application with static libraries of Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (Update 2).  We encounter on scenario where one bug was fixed in the library ATL-based applications and released in the MSVS2012’s 3rd update. We forced to rebuild this application with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (Update 3) and shipped in the production.

My question is how we can avoid such situation in the future.  Does dynamic linking solve such issue? But we need to install the redistribution package on the production environment.

Our application is in C++.

Comment: If you would link dynamically, that would indeed mean that you could have some sort of update system. This system would replace the shared objects that should be updated. Note that you will still not be able to update the interface (i.e. header files) to your shared libraries as that would require recompilation. Not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: This works both ways, they can also *break* your app with an update.

Comment: "how can we avoid such situation": what exactly do you want to avoid? That MS is fixing ATL bugs? Or that you have to rebuild? Or that you have do anything to get the new ATL into your product?